# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm developing Server side rendered react.js application.I'm using reduxForm  for signup component.
but i'm getting bellow error in console

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

```
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"redux-form": "^7.4.2"

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";

class SignUpForm extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);            

        this.renderField = this.renderField.bind(this);
    }
renderField(field) {
        const { meta: { touched, error } } = field;
        const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? "has-danger" : ""}`;
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <label>{field.label}</label>
                <input className="form-control" type={field.type || "text"} {...field.input} />
                <div className="text-help">
                    {touched ? error : ""}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

render() {        
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props; 
        return (
            <form >                
                <Field
                    label="Mobile Number"
                    name="mobilenumber"
                    component={this.renderField}
                />            
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-play">OK</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ signup }, dispatch);
}

export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: "SignUpForm"
})(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpForm));
```

Comment: Is it all the code from your file? Are you sure you do export all your components in the right way?

Comment: @Pietro yes.this is full code

Comment: @R.B removed bind from constructor,but same error

Comment: @Tje123 can you try convert your export to this? export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
      form: 'SignUpForm',
      validate
})(SignUpForm));

Comment: @R.B tried it.but same error.then i export like this `export default reduxForm({
    validate,
    form: "SignUpForm"
})({
    component: connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpForm)
});` . then got this error `Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()`

Comment: How are you importing the SignUpForm component?